# Does adding a network extension to a netlogo model erase the rest of the code?

Tags: dynamic, network-programming, netlogo

I am sorry for this basic question, but I just need a quick answer to a general problem I am encountering now.

I already wrote a model that includes two turtle breeds with different properties each, various parameters, and rules of behavior for each breed. I conducted a first run and analysis. I am quite happy with that model.

Now, I want to make it more dynamic by adding a network extension (preferential attachment) to only one of the two breeds that affects their behavior and their properties.

When I tried adding the network extension, it seems that all the code I wrote for each of the two breeds is ignored in the network, and I kind of have to recode everything from scratch. 
Before I write a new model now starting with the network extension and slowly adding the other parameters, I just wanted to ask if this is indeed the only way to do this to make it work properly.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in the code. That behavior shouldn't happen.

Comment: Oh ok, that is good to know, then I will first try out some other ways to add the network without changing everything from scratch.

Comment: Feel free to add code in a new question and we can help debug.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to make this work somehow first, I never used the network extension for own models, just in as homework, so I am not very familiar with it.